# Ruby, cucumber, calling a step within a step, within an if statement

Tags: ruby, cucumber

In a process of making Gherkin a little more readable, I'm trying to call a step within a step.

```
Given /^I am a user with a case with (.*) properties with X enabled$/ do |number|
  if number == 2
    step "I login as a, 1, 2 user with X num_of_properties_2"
    puts "prop2"
  elsif number == 1
    step "I login as a, 1, 2 user with X num_of_properties_1"
    puts "prop1"
  end
end
```

Neither of these will work, however if I do only

```
 Given /^I am a user with a case with (.*) properties with X enabled$/ do |number|
     step "I login as a, 1, 2 user with X num_of_properties_2"
 end
```

This works perfectly.

Any reason why I cannot call another step within an "if" statement?

Comment: Change your if condition to `if 1 == 1` - I bet it works then.  I'm guessing you're capturing a string for your number instead of an integer.

Comment: You are most definitely capturing a string. `if number == '1' ...` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the number with (\d+) instead of (.*).